# What are situations with western languages where you'd use HTML 5's Ruby element?

Tags: html

HTML 5 is introducing a new element: [`<ruby>`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/text-level-semantics.html#the-ruby-element); here's the W3C's description:

> The ruby element allows one or more spans of phrasing content to be marked with ruby annotations. Ruby annotations are short runs of text presented alongside base text, primarily used in East Asian typography as a guide for pronunciation or to include other annotations. In Japanese, this form of typography is also known as furigana.

They then go on to give a few examples of Ruby annotations in use for Chinese and Japanese text.  I'm wondering though: is this element going to be useful only for east-asian HTML documents, or are there good semantic applications for the `<ruby>` element in other western languages like English, German, Spanish, etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a linguist, I can see the benefits in using `<ruby>` for marking up linguistic examples with various theoretical notational conventions. One example that comes to mind is indicating tonal levels in autosegmental phonology. Here's a quick example I threw together that can be seen in the latest Webkit/Chromium (at least):

http://miketaylr.com/code/western_ruby.html

Currently, this type of notation is left for LaTex and friends, and if on the web, generally a non-accessible image.

Comment: I should note that the example is from Kikuyu/Gikuyu,which is in the Bantu family--not exactly "Western", but there are plenty of Western languages with tonal systems so it's not entirely irrelevant.

Comment: That's a good point. It's obviously not going to illustrate many-to-one associations with line drawing like the autosegmental tier notation that you use in your paper, but as an ad-hoc style of indicating the tone of each syllable it could be useful.

Comment: +1 and accepted due to the awesome explanation & example, thanks :)

Comment: @Nate

Yes, Tone seems like a better example. Cheers.

Answer (score 7):

<sub>id-ee-oh-SINK-ruh-sees</sub>

Could be useful for people learning English, as our writing system has many idiosyncrasies that make it somewhat less than phonetic.

Comment: I started to be thrilled only to find out that the example is ascii art!

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, ruby annotations are not really relevant in Western languages because Western alphabets are (more or less) phonetic. In Japanese they are used to give a pronunciation guide for logographic characters which don't have obvious pronunciations (unless you've memorized them). I suppose the Western analog would be IPA notation in brackets following a word, but those are rarely used and I don't know if Ruby annotations would be appropriate for them.

Comment: see miketylr's "various theoretical notational conventions" and Adam Bellaire's language learning. Mix them into learning technical stuff incidentally translated to your native non-english language.

Answer (score 0):

My list:

- theoretical notational conventions (miketylr's answer)
  http://miketaylr.com/code/western_ruby.html
- language learning (Adam Bellaire's answer)
     <sub>id-ee-oh-SINK-ruh-sees</sub> 
  foo  idiosyncrasies bar - made with ascii 'nbsp' art
- abbreviation, acronym, initialism (possibly - why hover?)
- **learning technical terms of English origin accidentally translated to your non-english native language**

I'm often forced to do the latter in uni. While the translated terminology is often consistent, *very* often it's not at all self-explaining or not as much as the original english one.

Also the same term may have been translated using several translation systems by different authors/groups.

Another problem group is when, for example, queue, row, series (and sometimes tuple) are translated to the very same word in your language.

Given a western language with less users, and the low percentage of technical people in the population, this actually makes learning the topic much easier directly from English and then learn the translations in a second step.

Ruby could be a tool to transform this into a one-step process, providing either the translations *or* the original as a "Furigana".

Comment: If understand you correctly, you're talking about using ruby annotations to encode translations rather than pronunciation. That sounds to me like a misuse of the element, giving it different semantics and using it only because it has the specific display convention that you want to achieve. It would be more appropriate to have some kind of separate "translation" display tag instead.

Comment: @NateC-K you're right, and I'd be happy to use that. also consider that misuse of elements already lead to the development of css :D